# Array Helpers javascript exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, helper

I am trying to solve an exercise about array helpers in Javascript, this is my code.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function square() {
    var arraySquare = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        arraySquare[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
        arraySquare.push(arraySquare[i]);
    }
    return arraySquare;
}
console.log(square());

function cube() {
    var arrayCube = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        arrayCube[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i] * numbers[i];
        arrayCube.push(arrayCube[i]);
    }
    return arrayCube;
}
console.log(cube());

function arrayAverage() {
    var sum = 0;
    var average = 0;
    if (numbers === []) {
        return NaN;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }
        average = sum / i;
    }
    return average;
}
console.log(arrayAverage());

function arraySum() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(arraySum());

function even() {
   var arrayEven = [];    
   for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
          arrayEven.push(numbers[i]);
      } 
   }
   return arrayEven;
}
console.log(even());

function odd() {
    var arrayOdd = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            arrayOdd.push(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return arrayOdd;
}
console.log(odd());
```

For some reason, the square() and cube() function, push the last element in the new arrays twice. Do you have any idea why this could happen? 
Aside from this, the code seems to work just fine. If you notice any other problem in the code please mention it!

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Oh man… all of these can be solved trivially by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) without such weird bugs.

Comment: @Xufox indeed but it must be out of the scope of the exercice

Comment: @Xufox truth is that I am still a novice in Javascript, and I have barely used map and filter. Still thanks a lot for your comments and for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting the `i`th element, and after that you are pushing a new value onto the array:

```
arrayCube[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i] * numbers[i];
arrayCube.push(arrayCube[i]);
```

You should probably just do:

```
arrayCube.push(numbers[i] * numbers[i] * numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies **here**

```
arraySquare[i] = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
arraySquare.push(arraySquare[i]);
```

You are updating the array two times, your function doesn't just add an extra final number, but it adds two numbers, one at `i` and one at `i+1` every time, the one at `i+1` get overwritten the next iteration that's why only the final one stays.

you should just keep the first line

Answer (score 0):

Checked for Square function. It worked for me.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function square() {
    var arraySquare = []; var a ;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        a = numbers[i] * numbers[i];
        arraySquare.push(a);
    }
    return arraySquare;
}
console.log(square());
```

Hope this works for both functions.

Regards,
Eby J